# Why aren't parts of the Concurrency TS going in C++17?

Tags: c++, standards, c++17

According to [Michael Wong](https://wongmichael.com/category/c/) the Concurrency TS is not going in, despite complete, apparently

> Although there is implementation experience, it was just approved and is too fresh to be voted to be added to C++17.

My favourite proposal was originally in [N3327](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3327.pdf) but I first read of it in N3857/[N3784](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3784.pdf) and had expected it for C++14. `futures` has had and implementation of [.then() in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.then) since 2013 and Microsoft has implemented a form of them in PPL so any issues will have been hit upon, discussed and corrected. An asynchronous version of `.get()` is a necessity and seemed to been decided upon since early-2014 when [N3865](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3865.pdf) ('More Improvements to std::future') talked as if `.then()` was a given. Which means even with 5 years since [N3327](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3327.pdf) first raised a `.then()` due to 'streamlining' any well thought out, discussed and implemented proposal is blocked by discussions going on that is tangential to it.

It is now going to be 2020 before it will ship.

**Is the Concurrency TS a whole or nothing proposal? And if so why?**

Comment: you can always implement your own futures, it's sucks, but you really don't need the standard for it.

Comment: I will just continue to use the boost implementation despite my dislike of boost.

Comment: The TS will probably be available prior to 2020?  That is what `<experimental/future>` is for and the new has_include stuff: you can start using it prior to it being in the formal standard, with a high level of confidence it will be standardized, so long as your build-chain supports it.

Answer (score 4):

> It is now going to be 2020 before it will ship.

It's shipping *now*. Just not in the C++ standard itself.

You shouldn't think of a TS as some kind of fictional document. It's a real thing, and many vendors implement TS's. Microsoft and libc++ have support for the FileSystem TS, for example.

With C++17 feature complete, compiler and standard library vendors have their hands full implementing those features. Not to mention the Concepts TS and so forth. So it's not surprising that the Concurrency TS isn't their highest priority.

As for why parts of Concurrency weren't added to C++17, the minutes of the Jacksonville meeting show that SG1 (the study group for concurrency issues) specifically proposed adding Parallelism TS to the standard, but did not do so for Concurrency TS. So they apparently felt that Concurrency TS was not ready to be added to the standard library, even partially.

Comment: Moreover Boost kind of implements significant parts of the Concurrency TS, so vendors are even less pressed to implement them.

Comment: @Morwenn: Boost implemented the FileSystem first, but that didn't stop libc++ or Microsoft from making it a priority.

Comment: Was it realy a priority? I didn't know that.

Comment: @Morwenn: Well, they both implemented it relatively quickly after standardization. That's pretty suggestive.